# The ubuntu 20.04 stucked at the starting screen

Tags: boot, 20.04, disk, lts

Ubuntu stucked as my computer shut down automatically I think because of some power failure i tried going to recovery mode f.. I dont remeber command its not working showing an error that the disk is mounted and when I tried to reboot again the ubuntu again stucked at the spinning symbol any solution for this ?
And I had installed the sys yesterday and its showing disk space full although i have allocated 90 gb to it i think some process stucked and it happen, I am beginner at the ubuntu anyone please help!!

Edit 1 : I have found out by booting from USB stick that the file named pagemap is taking all the space around 80 gigs results in no space for ubuntu to work I deleted that file and the system is again working fine as it should

Comment: If you installed the system yesterday, it might be easiest to simply re-install it today. Advice: Don't let your system lose power unexpectedly. That might cause filesystem damage (that you must learn how to fix) or data loss.

Comment: It sounds to me like the file-system needs to be checked (ie. `fsck` which I always perform before turning a system on due to power-outage). I can't provide more given you're not clear with your question (command you don't remember, unspecified error etc)..  What user535733 suggested make sense.  To provide more you need to be specific (exact error messages for exact commands etc).

Comment: Fsck is not working due to the disk is mounted